# After i have a javascript pop up telling users that their message has been sent, the header gets HUGE. How do i make that stop?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a form that sends the data in an email to me. After the email is sent, the users get a javascript pop up that tells them the message sent. When this happens the header section takes up the whole screen. And it stays full screen even if the screen is re-sized, it only goes away if I re-navigate to the page using the navigation, but I want the header to appear normally after the pop up. How can I fix this. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if($_POST["message"]){
        $recipient="laurapohl18@gmail.com";
        $subject="Customer Inquiry";
        $sender=$_POST["sender"];
        $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
        $senderPhone=$_POST["senderPhone"];
        $message=$_POST["message"];

        $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\n\nCustomer Message: $message";

        mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message has been sent");</script>';
    }
?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang = "en">

<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <title>User Based Web Design</title>
    <!--title displayed in the tab, search-able title of the page-->

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Reset.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Contact Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Navigation Styles.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "Style Sheets/Footer Styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header> <!--start visible header section-->
        <h1>Laura Pohl</h1>
        <h2>User Based Web Design</h2>
    </header> <!--end visible header section-->

    <div class="navbar">
        <?php include 'nav.html';?>
    </div>

    <article class ="main_contact">
    <!--Start article section. -->

        <h1>Contact Questionnaire</h1>

        <div class = "intro_text">
            <p>Please use the Contact Questionnaire below if you need to reach me for any reason.</p>

            <p>I take your privacy very seriously. I will never share any of your 
            information with anyone outside legal requirements. You will never be spammed or marketed
            to by any of my partners.</p>

        </div>

        <div class = "contact_form">

            <form name="form4" action="Contact Us.php" method="post">

                <input type = "hidden" name ="recipient" value ="1">
                <input type = "hidden" name ="subject" value ="Contact Survey">
                <input type = "hidden" name ="print_blank_fields" value ="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="_pid" value="154040">
                <input type="hidden" name="_fid" value="A7QPIZEA">

                <table  class ="contact_table">
                    <tbody>

                        <!--Row 1-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Name:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="sender" id="name" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box required" title="Please type your name." required></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 2-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Email:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderEmail" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box"></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 3-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Phone:</td>
                                <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderPhone" type="text" id="textfield2" maxlength="30"class ="input_text_box"></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 5-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 6-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">Preferred Method of <br />Contact:</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Preferred Contact" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_0"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2" width = "30%">Phone</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 8-->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Preferred Contact" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Email</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 11-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="1">Would you like a response?</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Yes</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="radio" id="PreferredContact_3"></td>
                                <td>No</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 19-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">What would you like<br />to talk to me about?</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3"></td>
                                <td colspan = "2">Existing Customer Inquiry</td>

                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4"></td>
                                <td>New Customer Inquiry</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--Row 25-->
                            <tr>
                                <td class = "questions">Message Text: </td>
                                <td colspan = "6" style="text-align: left">
                                    <textarea rows = "4" name="message" maxlength="800" id="Comments" class ="input_text_box" required></textarea></td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 4-->  
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>

                        <!--Row 26-->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" style = "float:left"></td>
                                <td colspan = "5">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" style = "float:right"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form> 
        </div>      

    </article>
    <!--end article section-->
    <br clear = "all"> <!--clear all formatting-->

    <div class="footer">
        <?php include 'footer.html';?>
    </div>
</body>
<!--End body section-->

</html>
<!--end html here-->
```

Comment: Maybe/probably because you're outputting your `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` outside of your HTML.

Comment: @kerbholz - is there a better way to have a pop up ?

Comment: Have you tried moving the PHP part of that script somewhere inside your HTML? Maybe after `<!--end article section-->`. Not sure if that solves your problem though